# Maven Profile reads data from Properties file

Tags: java, maven, selenium, properties, maven-profiles

I have a Selenium project which uses Maven as a build tool and I want to read different environment details (protocol, domain, subdomain, etc) from a .properties file. Would it be possible to use Maven profiles in order to run my tests on different environments such as dev, staging, prod based on the profile which I am specifying when triggering the mvn command?

dev.properties:

```
protocol=http
domain=domain.com
subdomain=www
```

pom.xml:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>pre_prod</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

mvn:

```
mvn clean test -Pdev
```

Data should then be retrieved in the java code using

```
System.getProperty("protocol");
System.getProperty("domain");
System.getProperty("subdomain");
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read different properties files based on a command line argument, could you not just pass in a string for example -Denv=dev

Then in your properties reader class have it init the properties file based on System.getProperty("env");

```
Properties generalProperties = new Properties();
    String generalPropertiesFileName = "data/"+ 
      System.getProperty("env") + ".properties";
   initProperties(generalProperties, generalPropertiesFileName);
```

Alternatively you can also pass properties from the command line to your POM in the same way -

```
<properties>
  <property>
    <protocol></protocol>
    <domain></domain>
    <subdomain></subdomain>
  <property>
<properties>
```

And then these can be passed in from the command line as -Dprotocol=foo etc

Hope that helps?

Comment: Hey @JackForman, many thanks for suggesting an answer on this. Defining a <properties> directly within the pom.xml file for handling the environments isn't quite a proper solution for my problem because the project will have to deal with testing at least 10 websites, each one with its own dev, staging and prod configs. In this way the pom file will become quite messy as there will be a lot of data added into it. In the end, my final maven task should look like `mvn clean test -Dbrand=ebay -Pdev` where "brand" will be one of the websites under test.

Comment: Ok, the first solution with the props files taking your command line arg in may work with that?  However there is probably something clever you can do with profiles that I dont know about

Comment: Just finished implementing the first solution you suggested, working great! Thanks once again!